# Redirecting to a file added extra returns in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, redirect

The following wants to line wrap the output:

```
ss "Call Info-.*66000" *1006*.log -Context 2,2 > ../test.txt
```

Why?

`ss` is a alias for `Select-String`.

Is there a way to make it not add linebreaks to the data?

Edit:
When it gets something like:

```
... 80 characters ... This line is too long 55000
... 80 characters ... This line is too long 55000
... 80 characters ... This line is too long 66000
... 80 characters ... This line is too long 44000
... 80 characters ... This line is too long 40000
```

it produces something like:

```
  ... 80 characters ... 
This line is too long 55000
  ... 80 characters ... 
This line is too long 55000
> ... 80 characters ... 
This line is too long 66000
  ... 80 characters ... 
This line is too long 44000
  ... 80 characters ... 
This line is too long 40000
```

IN THE OUTPUT FILE?!?!?!?!?  I can understand wrapping to the screen but the file?  That's just bizarre.  (The log file actually looks nothing like this and some of the lines are hundreds of chars long.)

Comment: So much for free speech... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
select-string "Call Info-.*66000" *1006*.log -Context 2,2 | set-content ..\test.txt
```

Comment: This works and I get why it works.  But WHY can't I assume it's not going to modify the expected output?  ?????  Line wrapping should be implement as part of "screen displine" not the file handling?

Comment: True, but you redirect the screen output with ">"

Comment: There should be no assumption of formatting until the media it is being formatted for is reached and the formatting displine for that media should be used.  For a file there should be no assumption of formatting unless explicitely specified.  This is like giving someone a mirror because they asked for a piece of glass.  You can assume I am going to use it to output to the screen, but there are number of other things I can do with it.  Every piece of glass isn't a mirror, and every output of a program isn't going to a terminal display.

Comment: The number one rule for designing scripting tools is do ONLY what to user ask for so the output of this tool can be used as the input to something else.